# Display message-form in between two forms (without user-interaction)

Tags: forms

I have an application where I can show forms depending on the flow of the process. 
The managing process lets the forms communicate via de Session-data, the forms are rendered in the Controller on a standard-way.
Sometimes the period between two forms is long and I want to inform the user that his data are being processed, without having the user to confirm this step.
I managed this by introducing an other form which is shown in between. This form submits itself by using Javascript (
window.onload = function autoSubmit(x){
        try{
            document.getElementById("myobita-busy-message-form").submit();
        }catch(e){
            alert(e);
        }
}
)
To make it more perfect I would like this form to be a modal.

Can someone tell me/hint me how to invoke a form via the controller as a modal (po-up)??